# Plotly dash callback order

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash app, where I query a database.
Some of my queries are quick, some are slow.
I would like to show the results of these queries in a table in a way, that first I would populate the table with the quickly fetchable columns, then add the resulting columns of the slower queries gradually.

My problem is that the rendering callback of the aggragate data only runs after all the queries are done, whereas I would like to see it firing after each query callback result.

Here is a minimal example, where I fetch some quick data, then based on the quick query I fetch a slower one. There is a rendering callback, which is supposed to run after each query callback, but in reality runs only once in the end. (For the sake of simplicity I did not add the table here, just a basic div. I run Dash within a larger django project using django_plotly_dash, but probably it is not key regarding the question here.)

```
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

import time

from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = DjangoDash("Minimal",)

app.layout = html.Div(
    id='main-container',
    children = [
        html.Div(id='user-id'),
        html.Div(id='quick-data'),
        html.Div(id='slow-data'),
        html.Div(id='aggregate-data'),
        ],    
    )

@app.callback(
    Output('quick-data', 'children'),
    Input('user-id', 'children'),
    )
def query_quick_data(user_id,):

    print("--------- query quick data ----------")

    return "quick data"

@app.callback(
    Output('slow-data', 'children'),
    Input('quick-data', 'children'),
    )
def query_slow_data(slow_data,):

    print("--------- query slow data ----------")

    time.sleep(3)

    return "slow data"

@app.callback(
    Output('aggregate-data', 'children'),
    Input('quick-data', 'children'),
    Input('slow-data', 'children'),
    )
def render_data(quick_data,slow_data):

    print("--------- render aggregate data ----------")

    return quick_data + " | " + slow_data
```

Upon opening the app, the terminal looks as follows, while I would expect therender aggregate data to run twice (once straight after the quick query):

```
backend_1   | --------- query quick data ----------
backend_1   | --------- query slow data ----------
backend_1   | --------- render aggregate data ----------
```

My guess is that the query_slow_data callback is called first and the render_data is only fired after. So the question is, how could I force the render_data to be called first.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct, this is related to how Dash actually works. At the initial call, `dash-render` will recursively look at all the callbacks in your app, and will order them in by the availability of the input ([read more from here](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#legacy-behavior:-using-timestamps:%7E:text=a%20callback%20function.-,When%20a%20Dash%20App%20First%20Loads,-All%20of%20the) to prevent unnecessary re-rendering. This is really important when you have a big dashboard. Imagine a dashboard with many callbacks, in which many are related to each other, if `dash-render` start calling randomly without proper organization, some callbacks might run in a loop, breaking the application or in the best scenario, making the application very heavy.

For your given example, assume that `dash-render` first saw `render_data` callback. When it recursively checks the callback inputs with other available callbacks, it will find out that `query_quick_data` callback's is ready to use (not output from another callback) so it will give it a priority. The `query_slow_data` has only one input and that input already came from the executed callback, so everything is ready for it can be called, while your `render-data` callback is asking for two inputs, one is available and the other isn't therefore, the `dash-render` will run the `query_slow_data` as you guessed.

I have been reading dash documents for a while and I have not run into any method in which you can custom the callback order to make a callback fire twice during the `initial_call`.

Comment: Thank you, so most of my assumptions were correct. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve the desired behaviour then? Like rendering after each query?

Comment: Sorry but I do not know. I have read the documents related to the callbacks but never read about your use case. My dash app is having multiple dropdowns where each dropdown menu refers to the menus above and below it for filtering, and I noticed that for each change I made, the call back will be called only once all of the time.